# Open an android activity on click in listview takes a long time

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-listview

I am trying to understand why a click on a listview item from activity1 takes a log time (around 1 second) to open the second activity.

It seems that my code has an implementation or a performance problem ..

- The first activity (Main) displayed a listview.
- The second activity (Detail_annonce) displayed details of a listview item.

Here is extract of code of my first activity (Main) for bind click on listview item :

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            Annonce currentAnnonce = (Annonce) list.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                            String titre = currentAnnonce.getTitle();
                            String cat = currentAnnonce.getCategorie();
                            String desc = currentAnnonce.getDescription();
                            String etat = currentAnnonce.getEtat();
                            String img = currentAnnonce.getImage();
                            String prix = currentAnnonce.getPrix();
                            String villeObj = currentAnnonce.getVilleObjet();
                            String codePostal = currentAnnonce.getCode_postal();
                            String departement = currentAnnonce.getDepartement();
                            String avatarUser = currentAnnonce.getImageUser();
                            String pseudoUser = currentAnnonce.getPseudoUser();
                            String dateDebut = currentAnnonce.getDate_debut();
                            String idAnnonce = currentAnnonce.getId();
                            String emailUser = currentAnnonce.getEmailUser();
                            String partel = currentAnnonce.getPartel();
                            String parmail = currentAnnonce.getParmail();

                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main_All_Annonces.this, Detail_annonce.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("titre", titre);
                            myIntent.putExtra("cat", cat);
                            myIntent.putExtra("desc", desc);
                            myIntent.putExtra("etat", etat);
                            myIntent.putExtra("img", img);
                            myIntent.putExtra("prix", prix);
                            myIntent.putExtra("villeObj", villeObj);
                            myIntent.putExtra("codePostal", codePostal);
                            myIntent.putExtra("departement", departement);
                            myIntent.putExtra("avatarUser", avatarUser);
                            myIntent.putExtra("pseudoUser", pseudoUser);
                            myIntent.putExtra("dateDebut", dateDebut);
                            myIntent.putExtra("idAnnonce", idAnnonce);
                            myIntent.putExtra("emailUser", emailUser);
                            myIntent.putExtra("partel", partel);
                            myIntent.putExtra("parmail", parmail);

                            myIntent.putExtra("parentAct", "AllAnnonces");

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                // get the common element for the transition in this activity
                                final View image_view = findViewById(R.id.allannonces_image);

                                //String transitionName = (String) view.getTag(R.id.allannonces_image);
                                ActivityOptionsCompat options =
                                        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                                                Main_All_Annonces.this,
                                                view,           // The view which starts the transition
                                                "transitionImg"  // The transitionName of the view we’re transitioning to
                                        );

                                // put more extras in the intent if you want, like the object clicked
                                myIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_IMAGE_TRANSITION_NAME", "transitionImg");
                                ActivityCompat.startActivity(Main_All_Annonces.this, myIntent, options.toBundle());
                            }
                            else {
                                // Code to run on older devices
                                startActivity(myIntent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

Here is the code on my Detail_annonce activity :

```
public class Detail_annonce extends Activity {

    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    LinearLayout btn_mail, btn_tel, btn_share;
    View bar1, bar2;
    String partel, parmail;
    TextView nbAnnonceActionBar ;


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.detail_layout);

        Typeface robotolight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        Typeface robotoBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
        Typeface robotoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf");

        bar1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.detail_view1);
        bar2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.detail_view2);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(2000))
                .cacheOnDisc(true)
                .build();

        Intent previous = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = previous.getExtras();
        final String titre = extras.getString("titre");
        String cat = extras.getString("cat");
        String desc = extras.getString("desc");
        String img = extras.getString("img");
        final String prix = extras.getString("prix");
        final String villeObj = extras.getString("villeObj");
        final String codePostal = extras.getString("codePostal");
        String avatarUser = extras.getString("avatarUser");
        final String pseudoUser = extras.getString("pseudoUser");
        String dateDebut = extras.getString("dateDebut");
        final String idAnnonce = extras.getString("idAnnonce");
        final String emailUser = extras.getString("emailUser");
        partel = extras.getString("partel");
        parmail = extras.getString("parmail");
        String parentAct = extras.getString("parentAct");

        ImageView image_txt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_annonce_image);
        TextView titre_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_annonce_titre);
        TextView prix_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_annonce_prix);
        TextView dateDebut_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_annonce_date_debut);
        TextView villeAndCodePostal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_annonce_ville_and_codePos);

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        Double latitude = null, longitude = null;
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocationName(villeObj, 10);
            Address currentFound = addresses.get(0);
            if (currentFound.hasLatitude() && currentFound.hasLongitude()) {
                latitude = currentFound.getLatitude();
                longitude = currentFound.getLongitude();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(image_txt, getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_IMAGE_TRANSITION_NAME"));
        imageLoader.displayImage(img, image_txt);

        titre_txt.setText(titre);
        titre_txt.setTypeface(robotoRegular);

        prix_txt.setText("€" + prix + ",00 EUR");
        prix_txt.setTypeface(robotolight);

        villeAndCodePostal.setText("Disponible à " +villeObj);
        villeAndCodePostal.setTypeface(robotolight);

        ////////////////
        /// DATE
        ////////////////
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date pDate;
        try {
            pDate = df.parse(dateDebut);
            dateDebut = DateUtils.getDateDifference(pDate);
            dateDebut = dateDebut.replace("-", "");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("DATE PARSING", "Error parsing date..");
        }

        dateDebut_txt.setText("Posté il y a " + dateDebut + "dans la catégorie " +cat);
        dateDebut_txt.setTypeface(robotolight);

        if (latitude != null && longitude != null ) {
            // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
            GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            LatLng ville = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ville, 9));

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(villeObj)
                    .visible(true)
                    .snippet("La vente se fait à cet adresse.")
                    .position(ville));
        }
```

}

Comment: Why not just pass the entire object as the extra?

Comment: @karaokyo How can i do this ?

Comment: The `putExtra` method takes Serializable, so just have your Announce class implement Serializable

Comment: @karaokyo It could be the source of the performance problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Android starts your new Activity, it executes all of the code in `onCreate()` *before* it displays anything.

Typically what I do (as a professional Android developer) is only grab the Views I keep as class variables in the `onCreateView()` and then put all of my populating code in `onStart()`. If it takes time for your Activity to show data after switching Activities, you can put a ProgressSpinner view in front so your user knows that data is still being processed.

In your case, absolutely take ALL of your Google Maps code out of `onCreate()`. Google Maps is extremely popular and sometimes the server takes a while to serve your request.

Side Notes:
   I agree with the commenter about transmitting your Object as an extra. To do this, you have to mark your Object as `Serializable`. [See this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android) *Look at the most highly-voted answer, not the "accepted" one.*

Modularize your code! Separate some of that stuff into helper methods which then get called in your `onCreateView()` and `onStart()` methods. It'll make moving code around a lot easier.

You should look into using a single Actvitity and just using Fragments for all of your separate screens (excluding popups). Fragments can help keep your code more Object-Oriented and keep you from repeating so much code. Google also seems to be pushing the Fragment-Decorator design pattern pretty hard. This, however, ultimately comes down to personal preference.

Edit: [More info about Activity lifecycle methods here.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#lifecycle-states) Notice how the `onCreate()` is called *before* the diagram states that the Activity is "created".

Comment: Nope! My current project at work is done with only one activity and all fragments. It's a lot cleaner than using Activities. It also gives us extreme flexibility when it comes to connecting functionality across stories. It all depends on your personal Design Pattern preference. I prefer a Decorator pattern, which Fragments lend themselves to.

Comment: and now read what Square guys think about fragments: http://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html, you know Square? picasso, retrofit, okhttp, dagger, otto and many more, could they be wrong? personally, i too, when i **dont** have i dont use them

Comment: I've read that, actually, and while Square has an impressive history of applications, I certainly am not going to base my software design decisions based on _their_ needs. I'm going to base my software design on _my application's_ needs. Besides that, Google has a _much_ more impressive backlog of applications, the depth of which I hopefully don't need to spell out for you. Keep in mind: they were porting an old app, not building a new one, and they didn't mention what their design pattern/paradigm was. They bring up valid complaints, but our code is designed for fragments and is clean.

Comment: and google guys mentioned somewhere that new app should be created using one / two at most three Activities, unfortunately i missed that and will be more than glad if you indicate that page

Answer (score -1):

Use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. This is will be good for you.

Comment: Why this is not true>